# uniform convergence of sequence of function

Tags: limits, continuity, uniform-convergence

I have a sequence of function $f_n$:

$$ f_n(x) = \sqrt{x^2 + \frac1n} \qquad \text{on the interval  } [-1,1]
$$

and
$$f(x) = |x|
$$

I need to prove that the sequence of functions $f_n$ is uniformly convergent to $f$ on the interval [−1, 1].

$f_n$ is continuously differentiable whereas the limit $f$ is not differentiable at $x = 0$.

Doesn't it contradict the theorem about the differentiability of the limit?

Comment: No, for the differentiability of the limit, the premise is that the sequence of the derivatives converges (locally) uniformly.

Answer (score 1):

For the uniform convergence notice that $f_n(x)\geq|x|$, but:
$$ f_n(x)-|x|=\frac{1}{n(f_n(x)+|x|)}\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}},$$
with equality just in the origin.

Answer (score 1):

We have $f_n(x)>f(x)$ for all $n$ as the square root function is monotonically increasing. Recall that $\sqrt{a+b} \le \sqrt a + \sqrt b$ (this is easily verified). Then 
$$ f_n(x) = \sqrt{x^2 + \frac1n} \leqslant \sqrt{x^2}+\sqrt{\frac1n} = |x| + \sqrt{\frac1n},$$
so that for any $x$,
$$ |f_n(x)-f(x)|=f_n(x)-f(x) \leqslant |x| + \sqrt{\frac1n} -  |x| = \sqrt{\frac1n}. $$
From this it is evident that $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$.